# Error syncing SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to synchronize my database from SQL Server to Mysql, but I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in php on line 36

Here is my code:

```
// connect to MSSQL
$koneksi=mssql_connect($server,$username,$password);
$sqldb=mssql_select_db($database,$koneksi);

// connect to MySQL
$koneksi2 = mysqli_connect($server2,$username2,$password2,$database2,$port);

// copy data from MSSQL to MySQL
$query2 = mssql_query("Select Jabatan, Nama, NIP from PejabatPenetap",$koneksi);
while($r=mssql_fetch_array($query2)) {
    $jabatan = $r['Jabatan'];
    $nama = $r['Nama'];
    $nip = $r['NIP'];

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($koneksi2, 'StoredProcedure');
    mysqli_bind_param($stmt, '@jabatan', $jabatan, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255); <-- this is line 36
    mysqli_bind_param($stmt, '@nama_input', $nama, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 100);
    mysqli_bind_param($stmt, '@nip', $nip, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 25);

    $res = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: @sashkello please scroll you will see OP added comment for line 36

Comment: @DipeshParmar can you tell me what OP means please

Comment: You shouldn't be issuing multiple calls to `mysqli_bind_param()` (which is deprecated btw, should be `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`), it should be one with all parameter types and bind references. Speaking of, you have no parameters specified in `'StoreProcedure'`. I suggest you [read the fine manual](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) **very closely**

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.

There you can see, that this function takes only vars and no literals after the `$types` param. So replacing `SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255` with variables having the same values should do the trick.